# Como inserir índice e elemento dentro de um array

Tags: php, array

Estou desenvolvendo um laço para comparar duas tabelas de um banco de dados. O intuito é saber quantas pessoas foram indicadas por um mesmo funcionário da empresa. Para isso, estou precisando iniciar um *array* da seguinte forma:

```
foreach($linhas as $linha){
  $varivael = array( $linha['nome'] => 0);
 };
```

O problema é que dessa forma só adiciona o último item da tabela, e eu quero que sejam inseridos todos, que fique da seguinte forma:

```
$varivael = array( $linha['nome'] => 0, $linha['nome'] => 0, $linha['nome'] => 0, ...);
```

Pensei em usar o array_push(), porém ele só insere o elemento e não o índice.

Como proceder?

Comment: Dentro do `foreach` tente fazer `$varivael[$linha['nome']] = 0`.

Comment: Aparentemente deu certo. Apesar de já ter feito isso outra vez, por alguma razão, desta de certo. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Só fechando a pergunta. A resposta foi dada por @Anderson, onde deveria trocar a linha `$varivael = array( $linha['nome'] => 0);` por `$varivael[$linha['nome']] = 0`.

Answer (score 8):

Se precisa apenas criar um novo array, indique isso na atribuição. Da forma que está na pergunta a cada volta do foreach o valor de `$variavel` é sobrescrito. Para acumular os itens nos array basta `$varivael[] = 'valor';`

Mude:

```
foreach($linhas as $linha){
  $varivael = array( $linha['nome'] => 0);
}
```

Para:

```
foreach($linhas as $linha){
  $varivael[] =  $linha['nome'];
}
```

Outra abordagem alternativa é usa `array_map()` para retornar um array com todos os valores de `nome` e chamar `array_fill_key()` para criar um novo array onde as chaves são os nomes e valor padrão para todos é zero no caso.

o `array_map()` pode ser trocado por `array_column()` caso use a versão 5.5 ou maior do php.

```
$arr = array(array('nome' => 'fulano'), array('nome' => 'beltrano'), array('nome' => 'doge') );
$chaves = array_map(function($item){ return $item['nome']; }, $arr);
$novo = array_fill_keys($chaves, 0);
print_r($novo);
```

[Exemplo array_map - ideone](http://ideone.com/RfeYvq)

```
$arr = array(array('nome' => 'fulano'), array('nome' => 'beltrano'), array('nome' => 'doge') );
$chaves = array_column($arr, 'nome');
$novo = array_fill_keys($chaves, 0);
print_r($novo);
```

[Exemplo array_column - ideone](http://ideone.com/YIcdqY)

Comment: Porém isto não resolve. Eu preciso definir os dois, tanto o valor quanto a chave dele, de modo que a chave seja $linha['nome'] e o valor seja um número inteiro que possa ser acrescentado mais para frente.

Comment: @RafaelPessoa o nome se repete?

Comment: O colega @Anderson resolveu. Estranhamente ele disse pra fazer algo que eu já tinha feito, mas que desta vez resolveu. Obrigado pela ajuda